# Flutter - get x not working with persistant navigation bar

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am using persistant navigatioon bar in my futter project. what I want to do is when I clickon the button from the drawer i want to change the active index in the bottom navigation bar.

I have used getx for managing the states but the state is not being managed and I am getting no error nor success response when I clickon the button from the drawer.

here is the code...

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final NavigationController navigationController = Get.put(NavigationController());
    return Obx(() => PersistentTabView(
        context,
        controller: PersistentTabController(initialIndex: navigationController.index.value),
        screens: _buildScreens(),
        items: _navBarsItems(),
        confineInSafeArea: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        stateManagement: true,
        hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true,
        decoration: NavBarDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          colorBehindNavBar: Colors.white,
        ),
        popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
        popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.all,
        navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style1,
        onItemSelected: (index) {
          navigationController.index.value;
          print("here");
        },
      )
    );
  }
..rest code
```

**drawer.dart**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    NavigationController _navigationController = Get.find<NavigationController>();

    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _navigationController.setIndex(1);
              Navigator.pop(context); // Close the drawer after navigation
            },
            child: const Text("Go to Order"),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _navigationController.setIndex(2);
              Navigator.pop(context); // Close the drawer after navigation
            },
            child: const Text("Go to SetMpin"),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _navigationController.setIndex(3);
              Navigator.pop(context); // Close the drawer after navigation
            },
            child: const Text("Go to Recharge"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**controller**

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class NavigationController extends GetxController {
  var index = 0.obs;

  void setIndex(int newIndex) {
    index.value = newIndex;
  }
}
```